# trying to create applescript to rename a file's metadata 'album' tag

Tags: applescript, metadata

I really hope someone can help me, I’ve been going around in circles on this. All I need to do is set the metadata 'album' tag of a file with a string. Here's the almost complete solution (within comments is where i need to process metadata)

```
on run
    set ArtistFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Select the start folder")
    RenameMetadata(ArtistFolder)
end run

on RenameMetadata(aFolder)
    tell application "Finder"
        set subFolders to every folder of aFolder
        repeat with eachFolder in subFolders
            my RenameMetadata(eachFolder)
            set theItems to every file of eachFolder
            repeat with theFile in theItems
                set strParent to name of eachFolder as string
                set strFile to name of theFile as string
                (* tell application "iTunes"
                    set album to strParent
                end tell *)
                (* set album to strParent *)
                log strFile
                log strParent
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
end RenameMetadata
```

Comment: Are you wanting to add the songs to iTunes? To use iTunes to change the ID3 tag, they first need to be added to iTunes (which the script can do). Are they already in iTunes, though? If so, it would be better to work with them with a script that works on a playlist or selection in iTunes.

Comment: thanks for your time jweaks. I had planned to add them to iTunes once I had updated ID3 album name. I don't completely understand how to get it working from iTunes - getting the filename and getting its parent folder. It seems a shame that I can now iterate through every folder and hold the name of the parent folder in a string but still not manage to get that string into the ID3 album name tag. I'll have to keep coming back to it when I have a spare moment (unless someone can help me...

Comment: The folks on MacScripter tell you the same: The dedicated application to maintain ID3 tags in OS X is iTunes, the Finder can't do it. On the other hand the Finder can browse the file system which iTunes can't.

Comment: Right, since the current folder structure gives the album name, you'll want to run it like you have it. Inside you repeat block, add a song to an iTunes playlist, delay 1, then change its album.

Comment: apparently finder can't rename ID3 tags, so iTunes or 3rd party software is needed. This would explain my struggles.